# VBA Debugging - step through main program, but run routines called from it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Say I have a big primary routine, that does many things and calls various other programs.

When debugging, I step through my main program with <kbd>F8</kbd> so I can see line by line what's happening.

However, when I do this, any routines I call from that main sub also get stepped through.  Instead of scrolling to that called routine's `End Sub`, and placing a Break, is there a way to have VBA just run that routine, but then stop when I get back to my main program?

Currently, I have two ways to do this.  Add a break in the line *after* I call a sub, in the MAIN routine - or - I add a break in that called routine's `End Sub` line.

For example,

```
Sub main_program()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:Z1000")

do_things rng

Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Debug.Print cel.Offset(1, 0).Value
Next cel
End Sub

Sub do_things(rng As Range)
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Value <> "something" Then
        cel.Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

So when going through my main program line by line, I'd like to be able to run `do_things` without having to put a break on `For Each cel in rng...`, or the `End Sub`.

I'd guess one solution is to have VBA just automatically `break` when it hits an `End Sub` line, or something.  I'm open to ideas, I have searched around and can't find anything really other than the current solutions I mentioned above.

<sub>(Sorry if the title is a little clunky, I couldn't really think of a better way to phrase it - feel free to edit).</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is - although it may not be obvious at first glance.

When you're in that subroutine (although it works on any routine), go to `Debug --> Step Out` (<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+F8</kbd>).

This will actually *complete* that routine, then go to the next line in the other code, if applicable.  (At first read, I assumed it simply stopped that routine at the current line, and would back out to the routine that called it).

For example:

```
Sub main_program()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:B10")

do_things rng

Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Debug.Print cel.Offset(1, 0).Value
Next cel
End Sub

Sub do_things(rng As Range)
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In rng
    cel.Value = "Test"
Next cel
For Each cel In rng
    If cel.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then cel.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
Next cel
End Sub
```

.gif of the above:

[image]

Edit: An excellent comment I wanted to add to make this answer more complete.  Per @MathieuGuindon, when the `do_things rng` line is highlighted, you can do `Debug --> Step Over` (<kbd>SHIFT+F8</kbd>) and *run* `do_things` completely, and it'll stop at that next line.

Comment: Note: Shift+F8 / "Step Over" when `do_things rng` is highlighted, would also run the procedure without stepping into it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Oh! Excellent to know (I added in to my Answer).  I have seen that, but admittedly never tried it.  Again, just by reading it, I would assume with `do_things rng` highlighted, and clicking "Step Over" would literally *skip* that line.  Not run it and pause on the next one.  Thanks again :D